# How to surround chordnames with bars?

Tags: lilypond

I want to make a line containing only chord names, separated and surrounded by vertical bars.
I have the following code

```
<<
  \new ChordNames \with {
    \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-0.5 . 3)
    \consists "Bar_engraver"
  }
  {
    \bar "|" a2 d a d a2 d f4 g4 a2 \bar "||"
  }
>>
```

It's almost working, and the result looks like:

A D | A D | A D | F G A ||

However, I want to produce something like:

| A D | A D | A D | F G A ||

I can't find a way to add the leading vertical bar. One workaround is to add an empty measure before the first chord, but that creates some horizontal space that doesn't look right.

Is there a way to force lilypond to add a leading vertical bar?

Answer (score 3):

Lilypond has different behaviour for barlines at breaks. Regular `|` bar lines will be invisible at the start of a line, `.|:` repeats will be invisible at the end of the line, double repeats `:|.|:` will have different glyphs for end and start of line, &c.

So for each bar line type there is a map to a left and a right type for use at line ends (or `#f` if not used).

So what you want to do is to tell Lilypond that the default bar line has both `glyph-left` and `glyph-right` (the second is missing). For this do

```
#(set! bar-glyph-alist (assoc-set! bar-glyph-alist "|" '("|" . "|")))

<<
  \new ChordNames \with {
    \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-0.5 . 3)
    \consists "Bar_engraver"
  }
  {
    \bar "|" a2 d a d a2 d f4 g4 a2 \bar "||"
  }
>>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot for the explanation!